# Build Windows perl module on Linux

Tags: linux, perl, makefile

I am in a bit of a bind, I need to get my hands on some perl modules that are available on the any of the repos that Activestate can access. But the module is on CPAN and I got the source code but when I attempt to compile it on Windows it fails. If I run it on my Ubuntu virtual machine I run MAKE and works fine. Is there anyway to have MAKE on linux compile for Windows so I can get these modules?

The modules in question are Net::SSH::Perl and Net::SSH:W32Perl

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Net::SSH2 is included into Strawberry, so it should be possible to make it run under ActivePerl

Answer (score 3):

Some of the modules not available in the AS repositories can be found here.

http://theoryx5.uwinnipeg.ca/ppms/package.lst

Comment: hmm interesting I will take a look I might find what need. Thanks!

Comment: @Solignis - I clicked save too quickly :) If you don't have a hard requirement for ActiveState, you may want to try Strawberry Perl as well, since you get a complete MinGW build environment that allows building of Perl Modules the "old fashioned" way, including the CPAN shell. http://strawberryperl.com

Comment: Perfect, I downloaded it and I already like it because of the CPAN shell instead of that PPM which was kinda cool but limited.

Comment: I don't know who to give the check mark to... You both were a big help to me.

Comment: Interesting dilemma... :) I'd say if both answers have equal weight for you, than it would be beneficial to bring up the rep of community member having the lower rep value at the time.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with ActiveState Perl: It's not really setup to build modules because there's no compiler. Therefore, you depend upon some third party to build and compile the packages for you. I like Active Perl, but this can be a pain.

Download [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/). Strawberry Perl is another Windows version of Perl, but it also comes with the MinGW development environment. This will allow you to use CPAN to compile the modules you need. You might even be able to install these modules in your ActiveState Perl installation.

Are you using Perl 5.12? The default University of Winnipeg package manager for that version only has about a 1/2 dozen packages installed on it. I've found more packages available when I added in the URL for version 5.10. Add in the URL http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/PPMPackages/10xx/ to the PPM program and see if its there.

Comment: I am using ActivePerl-5.12.2.1202-MSWin32-x86, I will definatly try Stawberry perl maybe that is why these modules don't want to build right.